# Why does full outer join in HIVE gives weird result when one of the join fields is missing?

Tags: hadoop, oracle11g, null, hive, full-outer-join

I'm comparing the behavior between SQL engines.  Oracle has the behavior I would expect from a SQL engine for full outer joins:

## Oracle

```
CREATE TABLE sql_test_a 
( 
    ID         VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE), 
    FIRST_NAME VARCHAR2(200 BYTE), 
    LAST_NAME  VARCHAR2(200 BYTE) 
); 

CREATE TABLE sql_test_b 
( 
    NUM         VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE), 
    FIRST_NAME VARCHAR2(200 BYTE), 
    LAST_NAME  VARCHAR2(200 BYTE) 
); 

INSERT INTO sql_test_a (ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME) VALUES ('1', 'John', 'Snow'); 

INSERT INTO sql_test_a (ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME) VALUES ('2', 'Mike', 'Tyson'); 


INSERT INTO sql_test_b (NUM, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME) VALUES ('20', 'Mike', 'Tyson');
```

When I execute the following, it gives me the expected result.  The resulting table contains two rows, with one of the rows containing `NULL` for the `NUM` field, because there is no john snow in the table `sql_test_b`.

```
SELECT A.FIRST_NAME, A.LAST_NAME, A.ID, B.NUM
FROM
SQL_TEST_A A
FULL OUTER JOIN
SQL_TEST_B B
ON 
A.FIRST_NAME = B.FIRST_NAME 
AND
A.LAST_NAME = B.LAST_NAME;
```

You can test the sql script here: http://sqltest.net/

## HIVE

In HIVE, however, if you were to try the same thing, the full outer join results in a table with two rows.  The row that should be the "John Snow" row contains `NULL` for the fields FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, and NUM.  The `1` is filled in for `ID`, but that's it.

Why such weird behavior in HIVE?  Is this a bug? Or am I missing something...because *Oracle 11g* seems to handle this much better.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I could not simulate the result reported by @Candic3

I used the below statements along with the same "select" query as in the question.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS sql_test_a (ID String, FIRST_NAME String, LAST_NAME  String) COMMENT 'sql_test_a'
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
STORED AS TEXTFILE;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS sql_test_b (NUM String, FIRST_NAME String, LAST_NAME  String) COMMENT 'sql_test_b'
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
STORED AS TEXTFILE;


INSERT INTO sql_test_a VALUES ('1', 'John', 'Snow');
INSERT INTO sql_test_a VALUES ('2', 'Mike', 'Tyson');
INSERT INTO sql_test_b VALUES ('20', 'Mike', 'Tyson');

SELECT A.FIRST_NAME, A.LAST_NAME, A.ID, B.NUM
FROM
SQL_TEST_A A
FULL OUTER JOIN
SQL_TEST_B B
ON 
A.FIRST_NAME = B.FIRST_NAME 
AND
A.LAST_NAME = B.LAST_NAME;
```

Please find the result attached.

However, select query would return NULL due to unnoticed minor mistakes like data-type mismatch between the DDL and the actual data (say, from flat files) or mismatch among the delimiter mentioned in the DDL and the ones in the actual data.[image: Query_result]

Answer (score 1):

In select statement you have used A.FIRST_NAME, A.LAST_NAME which is not present for the row from table B. That is why the null value. Instead use COALESCE to find non null value between A.FIRST_NAME and B.FIRST_NAME

```
SELECT COALESCE(A.FIRST_NAME, B.FIRST_NAME) as FIRST_NAME, COALESCE(A.LAST_NAME, B.LAST_NAME) as LAST_NAME, A.ID, B.NUM
FROM
SQL_TEST_A A
FULL OUTER JOIN
SQL_TEST_B B
ON 
A.FIRST_NAME = B.FIRST_NAME 
AND
A.LAST_NAME = B.LAST_NAME;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think issue with "(" after  on condition which is slightly different than traditional sql.

```
        SELECT A.FIRST_NAME, A.LAST_NAME, A.ID, B.NUM
                 FROM
                  SQL_TEST_A A
                     FULL OUTER JOIN
               SQL_TEST_B B ON 
             (A.FIRST_NAME = B.FIRST_NAME AND A.LAST_NAME = B.LAST_NAME);
```